# Remote linux using vnc and gdm without login

Tags: linux, networking, remote-desktop

I remote linux server by using `vnc` and [`gdm`](http://blog.sumostyle.net/2006/11/gdm-logins-using-vnc/). This link is very good but I would like to remote linux server using `vnc` viewer without login.

May I know your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ssvnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html), as it can store both passwords and keys ?